# Accessing TIFF files in file geodatabase outside of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, file-geodatabase

I am working with many .tif files in a file geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro. However, I want to use these files in a Python script outside of ArcGIS Pro.

How do I access the files in the file geodatabase?

I know that I can use fiona and geopandas, but I would prefer not to do that as I would like to run the script on computers which do not have ArcGIS Pro/QGIS.

Comment: You can't have .tif files in a file geodatabase.  You can have file geodatabase rasters in a file geodatabase, but only ArcGIS can read them. If you used Windows Explorer (or scripting) to move *.tif files into a folder.gdb, then move them out again.  You can use fiona and geopandas without ArcGIS/QGIS, but they can't read rasters. You can use rasterio to read (non-file geodatabase) rasters such as tifs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works